# How to add Section and TableView Cell dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview, uitableview

I have a button that when pressed, a tableview section will be added and will also add a new row to that section. How can I implement this programatically?

I have an array of cells.

Here are my codes

```
- (IBAction)addCell:(id)sender {

    UITableViewCell *newCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

    counter++;
    [cells addObject:newCell];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [cells count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      //this is where i want to adjust the row per section
      //this code hide the recent sections, only the current created section appears
      return [cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: What you've done is not a good way to deal with `UITableView`s! You've created `UITableViewCell`s elsewhere while it is recommended to be done in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You can do what you want by simply changing your `dataSource` and then reloading the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try reading this:

[How to display the UITableView programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333545/how-to-display-the-uitableview-programmatically)

[Adding cells programmatically to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429618/adding-cells-programmatically-to-uitableview)

---

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thank you, but I have no problem in adding cells dynamically into a tableview. My concern is how to add a section and a cell to that newly added section. As we know, we have to configure the ,- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView method to return the number of sections. I have a counter to do this when the button is pressed then reload the table after. The problem is how can I handle the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method that controls the if statement for each section to appear?

Comment: Please suggest links in comments not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, update your's datamodel(NSArray or mutable). Second, when you want tableview refresh, add a code [self.tableView reloadData];

---

oops, your code some strange uitaleviewDataSource, Delegate Method.

also, your have a some mistake.

why you implements numberOfRowsInSection return 1? very strange.

I apprecated below code.

CASE 1. No has DataModel.

```
- (IBAction)addCell:(id)sender 
{

    cellRowsCount++;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return cellRowsCount;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
      if (cell == nil) 
      {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      }

     return cell;
   }
```

your codes, dataModel(NSArray or mutable) does not necessarily need, so I simply rowCount variable added and your rowsCount of tableviewCell has synchronized.

If you wanna with DataModel, below CASE2. refer plz.

---

CASE2. has DataModel.

```
- (IBAction)addCell:(id)sender 
{

    textCount ++;

    NSString *cellText = [NSString stringWithFormat:"blah %d", textCount];
    [myArray addObject:cellText];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return [myArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [[myArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
  if (cell == nil) 
  {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }

  cell.textLabel.text = (NSString *)[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: The problem is how can I handle the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method that controls the if statement for each section to appear?

Comment: Multisection is mean equal 2d array model, if you want extend section, your's datamodel must 2d array implements. Also About tableView numberOfSectionInTableview method add a code return [myArray count]; implements too.

Comment: numberOfSection implements return [myArr count]; numberOfRowsInSection must implements return [[myArr objectAtIndex:section] count];

Comment: Still don't get it. I updated my question with my codes. Please see if this is clear to you. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add the new section and the new item to the array that holds the section and the items like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    animals = @{@"Section 1" : @[@"Item 1", @"Item 2", @"Item 3"],
                @"Section 2" : @[@"Item 1", @"Item 2"]};
}
```

after that you just reload the tableView wherever your logic needs:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```