# Programmatically adding UITableViewCell in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to programmatically add UITableViewCells in swift and getting the following error message:

> 2016-05-10 21:58:41.961 appname[28802:2378292] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'myCell''

I have the following in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
let myNib = UINib(nibName: "myCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(myNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
```

and the following in func `tableView`:

```
 var cell:UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewCell", forIndexPath:indexPath)

        print("setup cell")

        if cell == nil{
            print("cell == nib")
            let cellnib = [NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("myCell", owner:self, options: nil)]
            cell = cellnib.first! as! UITableViewCell
        }
```

Comment: You don't really "add" a cell to a tableview like that.  Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333545/how-to-display-the-uitableview-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you give the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1) a read. It's a long one and written in ObjC but well worth it.

For your question, you don't create a `UITableViewCell` like that. Try this instead:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath:indexPath)

if cell == nil {
    print("setup cell")
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I was able to do to get it working. This tutorial proved to be very helpful - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-register-a-cell-for-uitableviewcell-reuse

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create Table Cells like that but you need to put that code inside init not within the viewDidLoad:

```
   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "myCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: Identifier)
    }
```

But make sure myCell.xib exist in your project. To create it Right Click on the Project Directory in left and Select New File. Then Select iOS -> Source -> Cocoa Touch Class. In the class name use: myCell and Sub Class to be UITableViewCell. Checkmark also create XIB File:

[image: Preview]